# Angular: parsing DOM objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im using an external library that returns an object. I console logged the object and found out that the information im trying to dig can be found here:
console.log(object.helper.context.innerHTML);

Which produces a whole bunch of html as shown below. Question is, is there a way to parse the "#number text" part? The format is always: hashtag+numbertext. Note: I do not know beforehand what the number / text will be each time.

```
// more code...↑
<p><b class="ng-binding"> #55 text</b></p>
</div>
<div class="Body">
<hr ng-class="{highlight : hover}" class="highlight">
<p class="ng-binding">joo</p>
<i id="editCog" class="fa fa-cog" ng-click="method" title="Click to edit" ng-show="hover"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use jQuery selectors (angular.element allows only to find by tagname) to target the first `ng-binding` class and get its text. In case where all your `b` has `ng-binding` class, you could do the trick with angular.element finding for first `b` without using jQuery.

Comment: [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) or just vanilla JS? Same as you normally would without Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
var element = angular.element(object.helper.context);
var text = element.find('b.ng-binding').text();
alert(text);
```